# mysql select, how to

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I need help.
I have 2 tables with names `bkeys ( id, bkey, ip, user_id )` and `wp_usermeta` (yes, wordpress table, fields of interest are `user_id`, `meta_key and` `meta_value`).
What I need is to select all rows from bkeys + value of meta_value where key is nickname, so result will have fields bkey, ip and meta_value.
The problem is, bkeys table can have NULL for ip and user_id (meaning keys is not taken by any user yet) so rows with NULL for user_id won't be selected with query like

```
SELECT bkeys.bkey, bkeys.ip, wp_usermeta.meta_value
FROM bkeys
LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta ON ( bkeys.user_id = wp_usermeta.user_id )
WHERE meta_key='nickname'
```

what i need is that all rows are selected, even where user_id is null. Is it possible? If it is, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try moving the `meta_key = 'nickname'` to the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT bkeys.bkey, bkeys.ip, wp_usermeta.meta_value
FROM bkeys
LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta ON wp_usermeta.user_id = bkeys.user_id
                     AND wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'nickname'
```

Think about `LEFT JOIN`s as a two-phase filtering:

- First you try to join a row with the `ON` condition, else you join a NULLed row
- You can further filter the joined or NULLed rows at the `WHERE` condition.